# jQueryUI Autocomplete on multiple fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQueryUI 1.8 and it's autocomplete feature.

So far I have managed to get autocomplete working in multiple fields like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: "/auto",
        minLength: 2,
        dataType: 'json',
        change: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#Id").val(ui.item ? ui.item.id : "");
                $("#Info").val(ui.item.info);
                $("#Info2").val(ui.item.info2);

        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#Id").val(ui.item ? ui.item.id : "");
                $("#Info").val(ui.item.info);
                $("#Info2").val(ui.item.info2);
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is to save form with hidden ID when available or create a new record from fields auto, info and info2 if any of them is changed compared to database. Now this is working if I pick a record and modify auto field it clears hidden id like it should. But if I pick a record and modify fields info or info2 the picked id stays in hidden input which is wrong.

What is best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to clear `#Id` when `#Info` or `#Info2` change? You could do that just by listening to the `keydown` or `change` event:

```
$("#Info, #Info2").keydown(function() {
    $("#Id").val('');
});
```

Also, your change function is throwing an error for me, since on `change`, `ui.item` is not always defined. Here's how you could fix that:

```
change: function(event, ui) {
    $("#Id").val(ui.item ? ui.item.id : "");
    if (ui.item) {
        $("#Info").val(ui.item.info);
        $("#Info2").val(ui.item.info2);
    }
},
```

I wrote up an example of what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/dNdhk/. Let me know if this isn't what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly enough to make it work. Now I can move forward with this.